# Adding third party libraries to Sonatype Nexus repository OSS

Tags: maven, pom.xml, nexus, sonatype

Procedure for adding third party libraries to Sonatype Nexus central repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already explained in Nexus documentation : http://blog.sonatype.com/2008/11/adding-a-jar-to-a-maven-repository-with-sonatype-nexus/

Comment: This documentation is a little outdated. The "Browse repository" button is missing. Do you how it is done in version 3 of the nexus server?

Comment: Hello @OddDev, hope this will help you  : https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-uploading.html

Answer (score 1):

On Version nexus 3.13.0-01 through the web interface logged on as the admin, do the following:

You have to set up a repository:

```
Click on Capabilities
Click on Repositories
Click on "Create Repositories"
Click on "maven2 (hosted)"
Update the name to be "thirdparty"
Click "Create Repository"
```

Then upload your assets:

```
Click on Browse
Click on "thirdparty"
Click on Upload Component
```

Or do it via the command line, something like:

```
curl -v --user admin:admin123 --upload-file ./foo.bar http://localhost:8080/repository/thirdparty/somedirectory/casefile/123/foo.bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Maven deploy plugin,

1. In your maven settings.xml configure your local repository details [Check this reference](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/blob/master/maven/settings/settings.xml)
2. Upload your jar using maven deploy command, like below.

`mvn -e deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.myapp.fantastic -DartifactId=myfattasticapp -Dversion=1.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar  -Dfile=myfantasticapp.jar -DgeneratePom=true -DrepositoryId=my-repo     -Durl=http://mylocalrepohost:8081/repository/maven-releases/`